# CiviCRM error on Joomla 3.x - There are no public mailing list groups to display

Tags: joomla, error, installation

After a successful backend installation on latest Joomla platform CiviCRM does not seem to work when I try to publish any page. i get this same error message on all pages:

> <div id="crm-container" class="crm-container" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <style type="text/css" media="screen"> @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css); </style> <div class="messages status no-popup"> <i class="crm-i fa-exclamation-triangle crm-i-red"></i> <span class="status-fatal">Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.</span> <div class="crm-section crm-error-message">There are no public mailing list groups to display.</div> <p><a href="http://www.livewisely2020.com/" title="Main Menu">Return to home page.</a></p> </div> </div> <script language="JavaScript"> function toggle( element ) { var parent = element.parentNode; var className = parent.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } } </script>

Can anyone tell what this is and how to remedy it? here are links to the other pages with the same message:

- http://www.livewisely2020.com/index.php/homepage/mailing-list

Comment: chris burgess edited your question. Fred Sullivan provided an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check your directory and resource URL in the Administer CiviCRM section.
Make sure your permissions are correct for the user.
Clear the cache folders in Media TemplateC
Make sure your going to http:// or https:// not to http://.www